# Why do I get "CommandError: App 'app_name' does not have migrations." when using Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

So I have deployed my Django project to Heroku, and now trying to migrate the database. I have everything working fine in my local sever. Then I tried to run the commands in heroku, as below.
`heroku run python manage.py makemigrations app_name'`. 
This worked fine.

```
Migrations for 'app_name':
  contents\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Book   
    - Create model Category
    - Create model Content
```

Then of course, I tried : `heroku run python manage.py migrate app_name`.
But then I got this error `CommandError: App 'app_name' does not have migrations.`
I've done some research for possible issues, none of which were relevant to mine.
For example I do have `__init__.py` in the `migrations` folder inside app_name directory. Also, I've tried `heroku run python manage.py migrate` as well as `heroku run python manage.py migrate app_name`. 
 I'm very confused. What do you think is the problem? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Don't generate the migrations on production! Generate them on dev and add them to the version control and push them, doing what you do only increases trouble later on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I don't know why, but the following works for me (two commands in one line):

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate app_name
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in heroku's help article [Why are my file uploads missing/deleted?](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted):

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
> the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
> shut down or restarted.

That is you do generate the migration files but they cease to exist shortly after when the app is reloaded.

In general the strategy you take is not a good approach to migrations as this can cause various issues, let's say you have multiple production servers each generates their own migrations this causes a conflict! In your situation suppose you do migrate this way and then later you want to add some new models this again will cause you problems.

One should *always* add their migrations to the version control (git, etc.) commit them and push them to production (here your heroku dyno). That is run `python manage.py makemigrations` *locally*, commit the generated migrations, push them and then run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer. So I have to command `git push heroku master`, right? Not `origin`.

Comment: @Ryan `git push heroku main` or `git push heroku master` whatever it is.

Comment: Thanks. But as I've written above, I already did ```heroku run python manage.py makemigrations```. Do I have to undo the command? Since the migration has already been generated in the production server. Or do I just simply delete migration files in local and then start the process over?

Comment: @Ryan No, the migrations you generated on heroku don't _exist_ anymore they are gone, deleted. You just need to add the migrations in the local server to the version control and push them (Literally repeating what the answer says here...)

Comment: Okay now that is strange. I've done exactly as you explained. After generating migrations locally, committing, and pushing them, I tried `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. And the migration worked perfectly. However the applied migrations are : admin, auth, contenttypes, etc. So I tried `heroku run python manage.py migrate app_name`, and now I get the same error.

Comment: I'm very sorry am I lost? :(

Comment: @Ryan did you not use [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) to add the generated files to the staging area before committing?

Comment: This is the commands I executed : `python manage.py makemigrations` -> `git add .` -> `git commit -m "something"` -> `git push heroku master` -> `heroku run python manage.py migrate app_name`. Isnt' this correct?